# Is this November is a good time to go to Spiti Valley, Himachal India?

Tags: india, himalayas

I am planning to visit Spiti Valley in Himachal Pradesh, India on this November first onwards, and planning to be back by the end of the month. 
[image]
How is the road condition now? Local transportation is available.
[Direction in Google Map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Manali,+Himachal+Pradesh/Kaza,+Himachal+Pradesh+172114/@32.3396623,77.3416859,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x39048708163fd03f:0x8129a80ebe5076cd!2m2!1d77.1887145!2d32.2396325!1m5!1m1!1s0x3906a374a0af9f8b:0x6ec85005a1175d47!2m2!1d78.0709903!2d32.2275991)

Comment: Please be aware that the route you have chosen passes through [Rohtang Pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohtang_Pass) which has a high probability of being closed to traffic in November.

Comment: You can also see [this blog](http://www.khagta.com/2015/01/what-to-expect-when-driving-to-spiti-valley-in-winter/) which tells about the difficulties in planning a trip to Spiti in winters (November is winter for Spiti)

Comment: @RedBaron Thanks for sharing blog, its really help full. Seems to be, I have to drop the plan for November trip. Do you have any idea about the route throught Nako from recongPeo(https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Reckong+Peo,+Himachal+Pradesh/Kaza,+Himachal+Pradesh+172114/@31.8798719,78.0763462,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x39066a202036d73f:0xa3ad6f92a3b2419!2m2!1d78.2675478!2d31.5390437!1m5!1m1!1s0x3906a374a0af9f8b:0x6ec85005a1175d47!2m2!1d78.0709903!2d32.2275991) will that be safe ?

Comment: That route should be serviceable for longer than Rohtang route _but_ weather conditions can worsen very quickly in Spiti and there is a high probability of getting stuck somewhere without adequate support. You may be able to find private shared taxis from Reckong Peo but YMMV. If you are not accustomed to hilly terrain/conditions, I'd suggest you postpone the trip to summers (June) before monsoon when the area is a lot more accessible/tourist friendly.

Comment: As you mentioned, I have tried to reach Spiti on last April first week, but due to rain road was broken and we stuck at Spillo village (we have tried the route from RecongPeo). I think I have to hold this trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Last November we went and it was awesome. The sky was clear snow
>   started in the end. Got places to stay everywhere. Less crowded. I am
>   planning to go on this November as well.
>
> Last time visited Chitkul, Pin Valley, Kaza, Langza Vallley,
>   Chandrathal, Kunzum Pass, Rothang Pass and returned via Manali.
>   Beautiful and amazing journey.

Answer (score 4):

Everything we want to know about Spity Valley trip: available in this [blog](http://www.khagta.com/2015/01/what-to-expect-when-driving-to-spiti-valley-in-winter/). Quoting few important points I have noted in this blog

> In early November, when the temperature dips down to -10˚C, the hotels are closed for the tourists and the first spell of snowfall stops the government bus service from Kinnaur. The road from Manali closes much before that. The NGOs working to develop Spiti and some for their own development, postpone their activities for the next tourist season, leaving the people of Spiti to face the harsh winters head.

---

> Difficulty Level – Extreme

---

> Winter is not an off-season in Spiti. Living here in winter is expensive for a Spitian. So, bargaining at the home-stays with your logic of off-season prices is not only rude, its inconsiderate. Water needs to be carried from the hand-pumps. Add to it the cost of wood to keep you warm and the cost of fuel to cook food and tea for you. No one is giving you a place to stay to earn profit in the winters. They don’t want you to freeze. So I will advice you to be generous and grateful.

Answer (score 2):

November is unfortunately a wrong time to visit Spiti, as most of the routes that lead you to Spiti will be blocked due to snow. Rohtang pass closes for travelers in November. The most ideal time to visit in my opinion is after monsoons - July-August or before that. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am planning to go on this November from 20-30, already booked my tickets. Planning to take car for rent from Delhi onwards, let see whats going to happen. Looking for a good snowy season and clear sky full of stars :)

Answer (score 2):

November is actually not a bad time to be in Spiti. It will be very very cold though, but still bearable. And roads from Kinnaur side are completely open at this time but not those via Manali/Rohtang. I'm pretty sure you won't have any problem with public transport reaching Kaza. The local buses within Spiti might not be as frequent, and so about that best to check locally with some hotel there. Taxi, etc will be easily available though. Have a great time in Spiti!

Comment: Yes it was :) 
Very cold and not snowing till 28th. Went through Kalpa, Pinvalley, Gaza, Comic, Hikkim, Langza, Badal - Chandrathal Manali and returned.

Thanks for all the information

Answer (score 1):

**July** is the best time to visit Spiti valley. November is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you like real adventure (with the possibility of getting stuck), yes it is a good time. According to me April/May is the best time to visit as you will see snow and clear sky. The transition from cold harsh winter to moderate climate is worth visiting.

Check the blog. It captures the experience nicely. 
https://www.adventuren.com/blog/blogdetail/4816